# Create a clone input audio device in Linux

Tags: audio, fedora, alsa, pulse

I'm using a FEDORA computer to:

- Stream audio to a web radio server using an icecast client (BUTT)
- Record audio input using arecord

I can't do both because audio input is completely taken for one process. That's my audio configuration:

```
[root@FEDORA ~]# arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)
sysdefault:CARD=USB
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 2i2 USB, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
sysdefault:CARD=Loopback
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Loopback,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
```

Comment: Are both icecast and your unknown audio recording program configured to use PulseAudio?

Comment: the unknown recording audio is a simple bash script that launch arecord. Pulse audio is "visible" and configurable for both (on arecord by setting -D flag, on butt by GUI) but if I set pulse to one, than the other gives me error on selecting pulse or "sysdefault:CARD=USB" device.

Comment: I assumed that `pulse` would be able to share, but apparently this is not enabled by default. Anyway, let's forget PulseAudio, try `dsnoop` in both.

Comment: Thank you @CL. I'vre read documentation and seems a good approach, but is dsnoop something I need to install (yum install.... ) or it's part of some other package that I need to update?

Comment: Use `dsnoop` as device name instead of `default` or `sysdefault:...`.

Comment: I think I need to add some configurations, thats' what I understood from this http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#dsnoop because `arecord -L` doesn't show `dnsoop` as device

Comment: Just use it. `arecord -L` lists only devices that want to be listed.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*

Using dsnoop that point to my original and physical sound card, I can achieve what I want with arecord, for example:

```
arecord -D plug:dsnoop -t wav a.wav &
```

and

```
arecord -D plug:dsnoop -t wav b.wav &
```

Together, and also my streaming software (butt) that have as inputs:

- default PCM device
- pulse
- default

Answer (score 0):

After a similar problem ([Recording with arecord stops after 1h 33m Under Fedora 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457839/recording-with-arecord-stops-after-1h-33m-under-fedora-23)) I have switched to ***ffmpeg***